# isn't it possible to install mplayer and devede at the same time?

Tags: software-installation, dvd, video-player, mplayer

I use Smplayer which uses Mplayer, I want to install Devede to create DVDs that can be played on DVD players. When I install Devede, it removes Mplayer and install Mplayer2 which doesn't work with Smplayer. I reinstall Mplayer, it removes Devede

I tried watching .flv using smplayer with mplayer2 installed instead of mplayer, and it gives an mplayer error. Mp4 works fine with mplayer2 and smplayer

```
/usr/bin/mplayer -noquiet -nofs -nomouseinput -sub-fuzziness 1 -identify -slave -vo xv -ao pulse -nokeepaspect -nodr -double -input nodefault-bindings:conf=/dev/null -stop-xscreensaver -wid 77594663 -monitorpixelaspect 1 -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-line-spacing 0 -ass-font-scale 1 -noflip-hebrew -ass-styles /home/elie/.config/smplayer/styles.ass -subfont-autoscale 0 -subfont-osd-scale 20 -subfont-text-scale 20 -subcp CP1256 -vid 0 -aid 0 -subpos 100 -volume 62 -cache 2048 -ss 572 -osdlevel 0 -vf-add screenshot -noslices -channels 2 -af scaletempo,equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 -softvol -softvol-max 110 /home/elie/Videos/Youtube Videos/Chess/Chess_openings_Slav_Defence_small.flv

Unknown option on the command line: --noflip-hebrew
Error parsing option on the command line: -noflip-hebrew
MPlayer2 2.0-701-gd4c5b7f-2ubuntu2 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
ID_EXIT=NONE
```

Comment: Mplayer2 works fine with smplayer. Indeed, when I installed smplayer, mplayer2 was installed automatically. And installing devede doesn't remove mplayer2 for me, only libavcodec54. I'm on 14.04

Comment: @muru please read my edit

Comment: I would help if I get what you are asking.

Comment: @Andrew I use smplayer video player, it uses mplayer by default. I install devede to burn DVDs, when installed, devede removes mplayer and install mplayer2 instead. Mplayer2 gives errors described above when playing certain formats. I would like either to fix these issues or to install mplayer alongside mplayer2. I do not want mplayer to be removed during the installation of mplayer2

Comment: @fischer I will think of a way.

Comment: @Fischer are you online?

Comment: @Andrew yes why?

Comment: @Fischer okay...

Comment: @Fischer http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16489/isnt-it-possible-to-install-mplayer-and-devede-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit the .deb file to allow installation

First, find the DEVEDE .deb file, usually in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Copy the full path to the DEB file.

Then:

```
$ cd `mktemp -d`
$ dpkg-deb -e "</path/to/devede.deb>"
$ dpkg-deb -x "</path/to/devede.deb>" .
```

Now try to edit the control file with your text editor (`gedit` in this example) and change the dependencies:

```
$ gedit DEBIAN/control
```

In the `Depends:` line you will see there `..., mplayer2, ...` now add `mplayer` and change that to:

```
..., mplayer2 | mplayer, ...
```

Save & Close.

Now run these commands:

```
$ dpkg-deb -b . "<newpackage.deb>"
$ sudo dpkg -i "<newpackage.deb>"
```

Welcome, DEVEDE!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you added a custom flag to `mplayer` in SMPlayer (at least, according to [this Ubuntu forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206564), it needs to be added). The option for [`mplayer2`](http://www.mplayer2.org/docs/mplayer/) is:

> ```
> --flip-hebrew Turns on flipping subtitles using FriBiDi.
> ```

Note the hyphen between `flip` and `hebrew`. Try changing the SMPlayer flag to `--flip-hebrew`.

Comment: Didn't work, I added those option